# How to burn fat while doing workout?

Tags: weight-loss, burn-fat

I use the food supplement [Le Carnitine](http://www.n11.com/arama?q=Carnitine) to burn fat. When using this, do i need to do cardio before or after workout? Which one is more effective for burning fat?

OR can you offer [another product](http://www.n11.com/fitness-ve-kondisyon/besin-takviyeleri) to burn fat?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a product recommendation request. Moreover, the links lead to a Turkish site, so the question, and its possible answers, are very esoteric.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't forget that you can't "buy" results. You can use all the L-carnitine in the world, which will certainly help a little, but unless you're actually in a caloric deficit, your cardio and supplements won't lead to anything but disappointment. I learned this through my years in high school, you can NOT outtrain a bad diet, so please make sure your diet is appropriate first!

For burning fat it's been proven that cardio **after** the workout is a lot more effective. This is because when you do a workout, you are burning the glycogen that your body has stored via carbohydrates. Since after the workout your glycogen stores are lower than they were when you started, when you do cardio you have to burn less glycogen in order to get into the fat burning zone.

This also burns more fat indirectly since the workout itself actually has quite an effect on fat burning. There is something that occurs called post exercise oxygen consumption, which is basically your body using energy in order to repair the muscles you've damaged through the workout, i.e higher metabolic rate. So, if you put more energy into your workout by not doing cardio first, this amount will be higher.

So that's 2 very good reasons to do cardio after the workout.

As for other supplements for fat burning, I won't give specific ones but there are some proven ingredients for this purpose. The first is the ECA stack, stands for ephedrine, caffeine and aspirin (ive never actually used the aspirin part I don't see a point). Just pure caffeine is also pretty good, it mobilizes fat cells for you to burn them faster. Yohimbe and l-carnitine have also been shown to be effective. Green tea extract helps with insulin levels and apparently has been shown to help metabolism to a very small degree.

But in my honest opinion, nothing beats a proper diet with caffeine as the fat burning/ pre-workout supplement in terms of pure simplicity, price, and effectiveness. The rest of the supplements you see have very questionable ingredients using bogus science studies to say false and over hyped claims to make people think they can "buy" fitness.